# Repeater button on click -VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a repeater control(databinded) with few text boxes and button in a panel.Now when i click the Edit button inside the repeater control,i want to show save button and enable textboxes (which are disabled on page load).For this how can i access the Edit button and write vb.net code for this purpose.

Edit button will allow the textboxes to enable and when save button is clicked the values to be saved to database.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like DataGrid is much more fitting in your case.

Comment: I have a panel of textboxes which can be visible upon the click of a row.hence i used repeater.

Comment: DataGrid has native support of things like Edit, hence I suggested using it. If you insist using Repeater look into the [ItemDataBound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx)

Comment: You can take advantage of Repeater ItemCommand event, on ItemCommand event, send command of button e.g(Edit) and check on ItemCommand event that command is equal to Edit, if yes that make your panel visible

Comment: AS I am new to repeater how can i access the text box in a repeater